# How to use Elasticsearch Rest api in java?

Tags: java, elasticsearch, httpclient, apache-httpclient-4.x, apache-commons-httpclient

I am using Apache Http client for making use of ElasticSearch Rest Api, but I am always getting HTTP error code as 200. Please help

Java code

```
import java.io.BufferedReader;
import java.io.File;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.InputStreamReader;
import java.net.MalformedURLException;
import java.util.Scanner;

import org.apache.http.HttpResponse;
import org.apache.http.client.methods.HttpPost;
import org.apache.http.entity.StringEntity;
import org.apache.http.impl.client.DefaultHttpClient;

public class ApacheHttpClientPost {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        String path="C:\\Tools\\ElasticSearchApi\\javadoc.txt", filecontent="";
        ApacheHttpClientPost apacheHttpClientPost = new ApacheHttpClientPost();
        try {
            DefaultHttpClient httpClient = new DefaultHttpClient();
            HttpPost postRequest = new HttpPost("http://localhost:9200/versioneg/message/_percolate");
            filecontent=apacheHttpClientPost.readFileContent(path);
            System.out.println(filecontent);
            StringEntity input = new StringEntity(filecontent);
            input.setContentType("application/json");
            postRequest.setEntity(input);
            HttpResponse response = httpClient.execute(postRequest);
            if (response.getStatusLine().getStatusCode() != 201) {
                throw new RuntimeException("Failed : HTTP error code : " + response.getStatusLine().getStatusCode());
            }
            BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader((response.getEntity().getContent())));
            String output;
            System.out.println("Output from Server .... \n");
            while ((output = br.readLine()) != null) {

                System.out.println(output);
            }
            httpClient.getConnectionManager().shutdown();
        } catch (MalformedURLException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }

    private String readFileContent(String pathname) throws IOException {

        File file = new File(pathname);
        StringBuilder fileContents = new StringBuilder((int)file.length());
        Scanner scanner = new Scanner(file);
        String lineSeparator = System.getProperty("line.separator");

        try {
            while(scanner.hasNextLine()) {        
                fileContents.append(scanner.nextLine() + lineSeparator);
            }
            return fileContents.toString();
        } finally {
            scanner.close();
        }
    }
}
```

Console

```
{
   "doc": {
      "os": "Linux",
      "product": {
         "name": "abc",
         "version": 10.1,
         "configversion": 1,
         "arch": 32,
         "license": "commercial",
         "db": {
            "@type": "Oracle"
         }
      }
   }
}

Exception in thread "main" java.lang.RuntimeException: Failed : HTTP error code : 200
    at com.informatica.zanshin.esapi.utils.ApacheHttpClientPost.main(ApacheHttpClientPost.java:31)
```

Here is elasticsearch sense screenshot

[image]

Comment: Out of curiosity, why did you pick status code 201 as the value to check against?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Status Code 200 stands for 'OK'
 [check w3c ref](http://www.w3.org/Protocols/rfc2616/rfc2616-sec10.html#sec10.2.1)

You should use

```
    if(response.getStatusLine().getStatusCode() != 200){
        // Throw exception or something else
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

After little modification your code will run. As **DefaultHttpClient** is now depreciated, you need to use **HttpClient** and there is no need to change status code because I verified it that in post request it returns response code 201 and in get request it returns 200.If you know about fiddler, I have also attached the fiddler's session screenshot.  If you don't know about fiddler you can visit http://www.telerik.com/fiddler

[image]

```
try {
    HttpClient httpClient = HttpClientBuilder.create().build();
    HttpPost postRequest = new HttpPost("http://localhost:9200/versioneg/message/");

    StringEntity requestEntity = new StringEntity(resultJsonObject.toString(), ContentType.APPLICATION_JSON);
    System.out.println("resultJsonobject:  "+ resultJsonObject.toString());

    postRequest.setEntity(requestEntity);
    HttpResponse response = httpClient.execute(postRequest);
    if (response.getStatusLine().getStatusCode() != 201) {
        throw new RuntimeException("Failed : HTTP error code : " + response.getStatusLine().getStatusCode());
    }
    BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader((response.getEntity().getContent())));
    String output;
    System.out.println("Output from Server .... \n");
    while ((output = br.readLine()) != null) {
        System.out.println(output);
    }
} catch (Exception e) {
    e.printStackTrace();
}
```