# Elasticsearch Java client: can't connect to the remote server

Tags: java, elasticsearch

I need to connect to the remotely located ElasticSearch index, using the url provided here:
http://api.exiletools.com/info/indexer.html

However, I can't figure out how to do this in Java.

[Docs on ES Java Client](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/client/java-api/1.7/transport-client.html) don't really have much info at all.
I also did not find any JavaDocs for it, do they exist?

Now, there are working examples written in Python, which confirm that the server is up and running, connection part looks like this:

```
es = Elasticsearch([{
  'host':'api.exiletools.com',
  'port':80,
  'http_auth':'apikey:DEVELOPMENT-Indexer'
}])
```

What I tried to do:

```
client = new TransportClient()
                    .addTransportAddress(new InetSocketTransportAddress("apikey:DEVELOPMENT-Indexer@api.exiletools.com/index", 9300));
```

also tried ports 9200 and 80

This results in:
java.nio.channels.UnresolvedAddressException
and NoNodeAvailableException

Comment: is the url accessible from where you are running this i.e. api.exiletools.com?

Comment: Well as I said I have a working Python script using this url.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The Shop Indexer API offers an HTTP entry point on port 80 to communicate with their ES cluster via the HTTP protocol. The ES `TransportClient` is not the correct client to use for that as it will only communicate via TCP.

Since Elasticsearch doesn't provide an HTTP client out of the box, you need to either use a specific library for that (like e.g. [Jest](https://github.com/searchbox-io/Jest)) or you can roll up your own REST  client.

An easy way to achieve the latter would be using Spring's [`RestTemplate`](http://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/web/client/RestTemplate.html):

```
// create the REST template
RestTemplate rest = new RestTemplate()
// add the authorization header
HttpHeaders headers = new HttpHeaders();
headers.add("Authorization", "DEVELOPMENT-Indexer");

// define URL and query
String url = "http://api.exiletools.com/index/_search";
String allQuery = "{\"query\":{\"matchAll\":{}}}";

// make the request
HttpEntity<String> httpReq = new HttpEntity<String>(allQuery, headers);
ResponseEntity<String> resp = rest.exchange(url, HttpMethod.POST, httpReq, String.class)

// retrieve the JSON response
String body = resp.getBody();
```

Comment: Yeah the service owner just confirmed this, he cannot allow access for the native ES Java client as he can't secure it without using Shield...

I'd like to avoid using Spring, so I'll look into this Jest project

Comment: It's definitely possible for him to secure the native ES client [with Shield](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/shield/current/_using_elasticsearch_java_clients_with_shield.html). Anyway, note that it is also possible with a bare [Apache HTTP client](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25117724/how-to-use-elasticsearch-rest-api-in-java) if that's ok with you. Basically, any Java HTTP client library will work, just pick the one you like.

Comment: Just tried this method using Spring and it worked right away, thanks, got the response from the server. Jest library didn't work for some reason, kept throwing malformed json exceptions regardless of what queries you sent.